# Rename files in a folder with out renaming the extension using java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to rename files in a folder with csv file column1 value by matching column2 values & imagenames containing in a folder.as the imagenames and column2 values will be equal.I want to just rename with column1 value.how can i achieve it..

i have written the code for getting filenames and values from a csv file.

```
File folder = new File("D:\\Imagefiles");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file1 : listOfFiles) {
          if (file1.isFile()) {
             //System.out.println(file1.getName());
              filename = file1.getName();
            System.out.println("Imagename------->"+filename);

          }
    }
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Karthik\\Desktop\\Javatask\\csvfiles\\filteredfile.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        if (array.length < 0) 
            continue;
        System.out.println("--------->"+array[1]);

         File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Karthik\\Desktop\\Javatask\\Imagefiles\\"+filename); 
         f.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\Karthik\\Desktop\\Javatask\\Imagefiles\\"+array[0]+".jpg"));
    }
```

it is renaming but not matching with column2.My csv looks like below

column1,column2
Wine, ghf_10677.jpg
Green & Red,ghf_10482.jpg
Shaded Cream,ghf_10483..jpg
White & Orange,ghf_10484.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) this is how you could do it:

```
    File originalFile = new File("foo.bar");
    ...

    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(originalFile.getName());
    String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(originalFile.getAbsolutePath());

    File renamedFile = new File(originalFile.getParent(), "newFileName." + extension);
    if (!originalFile.renameTo(renamedFile)) {
        throw new IOException("could not rename file.");
    }
```